# Is there an ATI Radeon 7000 driver for Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, drivers, vga

The ATI Radeon 7000 is officially unsupported on Windows 7 (both 32- & 64- bit). Even legacy ATI drivers don't support this. Is there any way to make it work?

EDIT:
This is my second video card. My primary is an ATI Radeon HD XXXX on PCIe. Since I have only one PCIe and I want more LCDs connected, I need to add a PCI card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate to be the bearer of bad news, but it seems from looking over the subject that you won't find any Vista/Windows 7 drivers for the ATI Radeon 7000 that support Aero (and other niceties). The card was introduced in 2001 so I think you'll be lucky to find any Windows 7 64-bit custom drivers out there.

Comment: In fact I don¨t need aero

Comment: I think the built-in VGA driver should work with the Radeon 7000 - no feeling for what the performance would be like though. Have you tried installing the card and booting into Windows 7?

Comment: You bet I did, it was my first guess - but it ain't working. To be more specific It's my secondary card - just to have more displays. Primary card is ATi Radeon HD XXXX

Comment: I forget the specific requirements of Windows 7 but it may be that it requires DirectX 9, yet the card is only capable of DirectX 7. Just a guess though, but I figure you won't get very far with the Radeon 7000 sadly. :)

Comment: hmm - I'm quite amazed I can't run in even in safe mode or use it for Dx7 games.

Answer (score 2):

[This site](http://driverscollection.com/?H=Radeon%207000&By=ATI&SS=Windows%207) claims to have 32-bit ATI Radeon 7000 drivers for Windows 7 (I have not tried them, though). [This site](http://driverscollection.com/?H=Radeon%207000&By=ATI&SS=Windows%207%2064-bit) has the 64-bit versions.

[Microsoft Compatibility Center](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/compatibility/Windows-7/en-us/Details.aspx?type=Hardware&p=Sapphire%20Technology%20ATI%20Radeon%207000%20PCIE%20DDR%2064MB%20Graphics%20Card&v=Sapphire%20Technology&uid=100945L&l=en-US&pf=0&pi=2&s=ATI%20Radeon%207000&os=32-bit) suggests that this will work.

There are sites that suggest that the drivers must support DirectX 9 in order for Windows 7 to run. Unfortunately, ATI Radeon 7000 is only DirectX 7.

Comment: I got that far, but installer won't install it and the driver ain't present even if I search it manualy (There are just two driver files CH_84684.inf and C7_84684.inf - and non of them contain character sequence 7000 (or 7XXX)

Comment: And for the compatibility - it's exactly this saphire card except its plain PCI not PCIE

Comment: W7 is reported to work just fine with [d3d7 cards](https://forums.guru3d.com/threads/best-ati-mobility-radeon-7500-driver-for-w7.412066/).

Answer (score 1):

you can use windows xp drivers for this card in windows vista/7/8... but you won't have the aero.

to install windows xp drivers, you have to run the driver install program in xp compatibility mode.

default vga drivers will also work with this card, but on the dual vga radeon 7000 series, you won't get both vga ports to work without the xp radeon 7000 series driver

Comment: Won't even work at all on Windows 8 and above, as XPDM/XDDM support was dropped completely (in favor of WDDM).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. Dell provides it for Windows 2008 64bit, for example for PowerEdge 1425 SC series.

ftp://ftp.dell.com/Pages/Drivers/poweredge-1425sc.html

ftp://ftp.dell.com/video/ATI_Radeon-7000M_A00_R177829.exe

It should work on Windows 7 too.

Comment: I'm downloading the driver from http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=CPWTC - I'll post the results

Answer (score 0):

Here you are.
ATI ES1000 (RN50), Radeon 7000 (RV100) x64 driver:

https://yadi.sk/d/YdcwBt5LyV3SH

This is my modification to some official Intel's driver. I modified it so it can support higher resolutions and hardware acceleration. DirectDraw and Direct3D are also enabled. Basically, I have copied registry settings from 6.11 catalyst and pasted them into this driver.

I recommend setting 16 bit desktop color mode, as this card is very old and has low onboard memory.

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  This is an ancient question that already has some links to official sources.  It's great that you're sharing this file but realistically, nobody with common sense will download an unknown file, especially one known to contain unofficial modifications, and especially from a new user with no track record on the site.  But other than that, thanks for trying to help with this question.  :-)

Comment: Really? I posted it here, because I had that problem. And this doesn't have an easy fix. The official drivers by Intel are indeed x64 compatible, but they are reduced versions. You only can set pre-defined resolutions like 1024x768, 1280x1024 up to 1600x1200. No widescreen support. Also, these drivers lack any of hardware acceleration, so everything is so slow. Scrolling down a page in Firefox for example takes seconds to redraw. These official drivers are useless, because you can use the Standard VGA driver with the same success.

Comment: The binary files are the same. Only several modifications to the INF file involved. So 100% safe here. If you had to use the ES1000 today, you would know.

Comment: The proper answer would be for you to share (in the answer) the changes you make to the inf file, together with an explanation of why you made those changes.

Answer (score 0):

I just purchased a ATI Radeon 7000 PCI video card Installed it in my server board S5000VSA and running win 7 Pro. It found and installed the drivers properly and is running ok. I know it is an older card but it is better than the onboard output and is stable. I had to remove a Nvidia because the drivers caused it to crash all the time..

Comment: This would be a better answer if you say where you found the driver.

Comment: I did not have to find the drivers as my system had drivers and somehow it came back a said that it successfully installed the drivers and is running without a hitch. It claims they are ATL drivers from 2009.